# React Router render information depending on URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

So im trying to learn React, im working on a project where i want to render articles about cars. I have my CarContext

```
export const CarProvider = (props) => {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState([
    {
      name: 'Car1',
      img: car1,
      id: 1,
      info:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum qui unde voluptate numquam aspernatur dolor sunt ducimus dolore nesciunt. Voluptate suscipit omnis velit maxime explicabo dicta at quo modi placeat',
    },
    {
      name: 'car2',
      img: car2,
      id: 2,
      info:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum qui unde voluptate numquam aspernatur dolor sunt ducimus dolore nesciunt. Voluptate suscipit omnis velit maxime explicabo dicta at quo modi placeat',
    },
    {
      name: 'car3',
      img: car3,
      id: 3,
      info:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum qui unde voluptate numquam aspernatur dolor sunt ducimus dolore nesciunt. Voluptate suscipit omnis velit maxime explicabo dicta at quo modi placeat',
    },
  ]);
  return (
    <CarContext.Provider value={[cars, setCars]}>
      {props.children}
    </CarContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <CarProvider>
      <Router>
        <div className='App'>
          <Header />
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/articles' exact component={Articles} />
          <Route path='/articles/:id' component={SpecificArticle} />
          <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </CarProvider>
  );
}
```

I have created a component called CarArticles where i render out all articles (name and img) and a button.

```
import { CarContext } from '../CarContext';

const CarArticles = () => {
  const [cars, setCars] = useContext(CarContext);
  return (
    <div>
      {cars.map((car) => (
        <Card
          name={car.name}
          img={car.img}
          key={car.id}
          id={car.id}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CarArticles;
```

```
const Card = ({ name, img, id }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <img src={img} alt='img of car'/>
      <Link to={`/articles/${id}`}>
        <button>read more</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

When i click on one of the buttons a component SpecificArticle with static text "Here's the specific Car article page depending on which button you clicked" is displayed

```
const SpecificArticle = () => {

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>
        <h2>
          "Here's the specific Car article page depending on which button you
          clicked"
        </h2>
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SpecificArticle;
```

My question is how do i get the specific car info inside the 'SpecificArticle? If i click on article 1 i want the component to render info from object1... and if i click on article 2 i want the info from object2 like name the img and the information...

Answer (score 0):

### useParams

Consider using [react router useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params).

Example:

```js
const SpecificArticle = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

### CarContext

```js
// create CarContext using an initial object with 'cars' being an empty array
const CarContext = createContext({cars: []})

// put cars data into the context provider
const cars = []; // array of data
<CarContext.Provider value={cars} />

// access the cars using the context anywhere inside the CarContext tree
const { cars } = useContext(CarContext);
```

This is pretty simple actually, please study how to use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), which "provides a way to pass data through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level".

Comment: Thank you, I’ve been trying with use params and I get that I’m supposed to use it but what I don’t get is how I get all the information from the objects in the array. car1.name and car1.image for example.

Answer (score 0):

URL parameters are accessed using useParams():

```js
import {useParams} from "react-router-dom";

const SpecificArticle = () => { 
  const params  = useParams();
  const id = params.id;
  
  return (
    <div>This is the id : {id}</div>
  )
 }
```

Since you want to use a [Context Provider](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextprovider), it should be defined as

```js
export const cars = {
    'Car1': {
      name: 'Car1',
      img: car1,
      id: 1,
      info:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum qui unde voluptate numquam aspernatur dolor sunt ducimus dolore nesciunt. Voluptate suscipit omnis velit maxime explicabo dicta at quo modi placeat',
    },
    'car2': {
      name: 'car2',
      img: car2,
      id: 2,
      info:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum qui unde voluptate numquam aspernatur dolor sunt ducimus dolore nesciunt. Voluptate suscipit omnis velit maxime explicabo dicta at quo modi placeat',
    },
    'car3': {
      name: 'car3',
      img: car3,
      id: 3,
      info:
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum qui unde voluptate numquam aspernatur dolor sunt ducimus dolore nesciunt. Voluptate suscipit omnis velit maxime explicabo dicta at quo modi placeat',
    },
};

export const CarsProvider = React.createContext(
  cars.Car1 // default value
);
```

If only a few cars are used this usage should be fine, but as the project grows it might be better to load a json file or a database.